# WAMPSERVER 2.2 with PHP 5.4 is Running slowly on windows 8 pro 64 bit O.S with x64 processor

Tags: php, mysql, windows-8, wampserver

The `WAMPSERVER 2.2` with `PHP 5.4.3` AND `MySQL 5.5.24`  is Running very slowly on my PC, It's just hangs after some time.

My PC configuration :

- Windows 8 pro
- 64 bit OS
- x64 processor
- 2GB RAM.

I am not getting what is the problem behind that What is the solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8, in 64-bit and 2GB ram? Are you seriously asking why this is slow?
64-Bit OS requires the doubled amount of RAM for every program than a 32-Bit OS.

And windows 8 is a pretty new OS in a time where PC's with 4GB RAM became somewhat standard.

Open a few programs and 2GB are full, how do you expect Apache AND MySQL to operate there manually?

For example I have a PC here with 8GB ram currently running MYSQL, Apache, PHPStorm IDE, Thunderbird, Firefox and Spotify and I am @ 4,6 GB RAM usage. Even if I close browser, IDE and spotify it wont go below 2GB.

There is no way to solve this except buying better hardware.

Oh and a SSD could help alot aswell but wont be sufficient alone in your case!

Comment: ok.but If I install windows 7 32 bit o.s then can this problem of wamp will be solved or not? @Steini

Comment: It could make the situation slightly better but I cant really tell. The RAM usage always depends on side-programs. I am pretty sure you want to use any editor, webbrowser and stuff aswell to work on that website which will also use hardware resources. I dont think its possible to make a non lagging webserver with 2GB RAM at all. Atleast not on Windows. On Linux you might have a chance. However If you cant affort new hardware maybe look for renting a small virtual server or webspace for 5-10 euro a month~ ?